# What are the regulated exchanges out there?

Tags: exchanges

I do not have trust in random exchanges.

I'm looking for regulated exchange so I'm less likely to lose my BTC.

What are the regulated exchanges out there?

---

Some hints:

- https://techcrunch.com/2015/01/25/coinbase-us-bitcoin-exchange/
- [What changed about coinbase.com to make it a "regulated exchange"?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/35734/what-changed-about-coinbase-com-to-make-it-a-regulated-exchange)

Answer (score -1):

You are always taking a risk having your BTC on an exchange. By sending BTC to an exchange you pretty much trade your BTC for their tokens that you can later trade back to BTC, assuming they don't get hacked, seized by the FBI or just steal them.

If you are planning exchanging BTC to another currency i would recommend withdrawing the other currency asap from the exchange. The only reason for leaving your money on an exchange is to daytrade. Most people that daytrade will lose money doing it and not even realize it.
You might make a profit if you compare your initial fiat investment to your current fiat value. What you need to consider is if you made a profit compared to just holding BTC. You should also consider the risk of something happening to the exchange and the risk increased with time as long as you have your money on an exchange.

Comment: That doesn't really answer his question :)

Comment: ```less likely to lose my BTC``` - of course I'm aware of the risk...